# Helm template: commas break syntax highlight

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax, yaml, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm using a comma in a Go template action

```yaml
metadata:
  name: {{ $route.name }}-route
  annotations:
    konghq.com/strip-path: {{ default true $route.stripPath | quote }}
    {{- if ne (len $route.plugins) 0 }}
    {{- $pluginsString := join "," $route.plugins }}
    konghq.com/plugins: {{ $pluginsString | quote }}
    {{- end }}
```

This is what my syntax highlight looks like:
[image]

And then that "error"/"broken syntax" then propagates to the rest of the file, basically showing everything with the same color, which is very annoying.

Is there a way to prevent commas from breaking the syntax highlight in VS Code?

Comment: What is the file type in your VSCode?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk the file has `.yaml` extension and the language mode selected (bottom-right corner of VSCode) is "YAML": in fact, the previous part of the syntax highlight works fine, but when I enter a comma as in the snippet, it breaks the rest

Comment: Try to change the file type to "helm-template"

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I face the same issue :(

Comment: Hmm strange, in my vscode it doesn't work with "yaml" but works well with "helm-template" :/

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk do you by chance use any VSCode extension?

Comment: I use `YAML` and `Kubernetes` extensions if that could help. Same as Shayki, your snippet only works with `helm-template` language mode

Comment: @Benbb96 installing the Kubernetes extension appearently fixed it, and here's the funny part: when Shayki said to try change the file type, I thought it meant to change the file extension, because I didn't have any language mode entry for "helm template" (actually it didn't make any sense, given its format, but I thought it was some kind of strange non-standard file extension). However, the helm template language mode gets added with the **Kubernetes extensions**, and VS Code also automatically switched it to the correct one. If you want to write an answer I'd be more than happy to accept it

Comment: Thank you for proposing it. I've added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the [Kubernetes extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-kubernetes-tools) on VS Code adds Intellisense on Helm charts and templates.

Language Mode of `.yaml` file will be auto-detected as `helm-template` in the bottom right of the screen :

[image: vscode screenshot]